# Sum range up to, and after, a certain cell color or value?

Tags: vba, excel, sumifs

I have a spreadsheet that highlights specific types of Data, and I need separate sums for the values above the first Red row, and then another sum for the values below the LAST instance of a red row. I should mention the rows are conditionally formatted, but if I need a helper row to be inserted that is perfectly allowable. For instance, instead of reading the read CF returning TRUE, in column H could be an "x" every time there is a red row, so the sum could sum up to the first "x" and then after the last instance of "x".

The amount of data that is input, and the rows that are highlighted change with each project, so it cannot be a simple cell reference. There are usually more than just two red rows if that matters. Numbers are always in the yellow rows, so the cell colors of the values themselves are irrelevant.

For instance, for the example below, I need the first sum to return 6, and then the second sum to return 4.  (The cells are not merged, it just looks that way due to the formatting that I included in the snip. All values are in column G)

[image: Color Example]

**With Colors:**

```
Sub findRedsAndSum()

redCount = 0
For x = 1 To range("b65536").End(xlUp).row 'find last row
    If range("G" & x).value = "CG" Then  'find red cells
        redCount = redCount + 1
    End If
Next x

redCountAgain = 0

For x = 1 To range("b65536").End(xlUp).row 'find last row
    If range("G" & x).value = "CG" And redCountAgain = 0 Then
        range("I" & x - 1).value = sumVar
        sumVar = 0
        redCountAgain = redCountAgain + 1
    ElseIf range("G" & x).DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
        redCountAgain = redCountAgain + 1
        sumVar = 0
    End If
    If redCountAgain = redCount And range("G" & x).value <> "CG" Then
        sumVar = sumVar + range("G" & x).value
    End If
    If redCountAgain = 0 Then
```

> sumVar = sumVar + range("G" & x).value

```
    End If
    If x = range("b65536").End(xlUp).row Then
        range("I" & x + 1).value = sumVar
    End If

Next x


End Sub
```

I am getting a "type mismatch" error on the highlighted line.

**With Helper Column:**

The red cells in Column "G" (where the values are) now are filled with "CG" instead of being blank. That could be moved to column "I" if it needs to be separated away from the added values.

EDIT:
Still having an issue with the provided answers. The wildcard '?' characters in the list are causing my error, but I would like to preserve that feature if possible.

Here is a snip of the criteria:

acadia?realty?trust
agree?realty?corp
alexander?s?inc
alexander?s??inc
alexandria?real?estate?equities?inc

Comment: Is there a condition that is being used to color the cells?

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes, for the yellow cells it searches through a named range called "Criteria", which has almost 300 criteria, and the red cells are highlighted if column B contains "Capital Gain". I am trying to work on a helper column scenario at this moment, which I am about to add to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see you have merged cells in your example, but I'll give the code a shot just using column A 
[image]

```
Sub findRedsAndSum()

    redCount = 0
    For x = 1 To Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Row 'find last row
        If Range("a" & x).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then 'find red cells
            redCount = redCount + 1
        End If
    Next x

    redCountAgain = 0

    For x = 1 To Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Row 'find last row
        If Range("a" & x).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 And redCountAgain = 0 Then
            Range("b" & x - 1).Value = sumVar
            sumVar = 0
            redCountAgain = redCountAgain + 1
        ElseIf Range("a" & x).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
            redCountAgain = redCountAgain + 1
            sumVar = 0
        End If
        If redCountAgain = redCount And Range("a" & x).Interior.ColorIndex <> 3 Then
            sumVar = sumVar + Range("a" & x).Value
        End If
        If redCountAgain = 0 Then
            sumVar = sumVar + Range("a" & x).Value
        End If
        If x = Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Row Then
            Range("b" & x + 1).Value = sumVar
        End If

    Next x


End Sub
```

**EDIT**

using "helper":
[image]

```
Sub findRedsAndSum()

    redCount = 0
    For x = 1 To Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Row 'find last row
        If Range("a" & x).Value = "this is red" Then  'find red cells
            redCount = redCount + 1
        End If
    Next x

    redCountAgain = 0

    For x = 1 To Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Row 'find last row
        If Range("a" & x).Value = "this is red" And redCountAgain = 0 Then
            Range("b" & x - 1).Value = sumVar
            sumVar = 0
            redCountAgain = redCountAgain + 1
        ElseIf Range("a" & x).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
            redCountAgain = redCountAgain + 1
            sumVar = 0
        End If
        If redCountAgain = redCount And Range("a" & x).Value <> "this is red" Then
            sumVar = sumVar + Range("a" & x).Value
        End If
        If redCountAgain = 0 Then
            sumVar = sumVar + Range("a" & x).Value
        End If
        If x = Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Row Then
            Range("b" & x + 1).Value = sumVar
        End If

    Next x


End Sub
```

Comment: They actually are not merged. It just looks that way due to the formatting. My apologies. However, since the cells are conditionally formatted, the interior.colorindex actually is not three. It is technically still blank, so it won't read that.

Comment: I just edited my original comment. Unfortunately it won't due to the interior.colorindex. I cam working on a helper column now, and it could read that instead of the color? I will try and keep you updated. Thanks.

Comment: I am getting a "type mismatch" error on the last sumVar = sumVar line for some reason? I used the exact same code you dide, but I replaced the "a" to "b" in the 'find last row lines because that is where the longest column of data is, and I replaced any other "a" values with "G", as that is where my sum data is, and any "b" values with "I", as that is where I would like the sum to be returned (although, I would rather it be at the top of the sheet if at all possible in D6 and D7). What am I missing?

Comment: As I understand this the colors are via conditional formatting you will need to use the `DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` instead.

Comment: Frankly I would skip the color all together and use Column B and its value to be your criteria.  Then if the user changes the conditional formatting color and/or removes it altogether the sub will still work.

Comment: @ScottCraner agreed. i'd standardize the template a bit...the vba code i wrote is very cloogy

Comment: can you step through your code using F8 and go line by line and let me know which line is giving you the type mismatch? also, your ranges in the code you pasted seem off from what i pasted.  for example, `for x = 1 to Range("b65536").End(xlUp).Row` and `If Range("G" & x).Value = "CG" And...` should all be referencing the same column (in my example i use column a).

Comment: @jellz77 I highlighted it now. I changed those because column 'A' does not have the longest row, column 'B' does. Also, the information I need to search for, per your example "this is red" is not in column A, it's in column G.

Comment: @jellz77 Does the "Find last row" and the other ranges have to be the same? Even if I do that, I am still getting a type mismatch error.

Comment: @Excellerator you're getting a type mismatch b/c the sumvar line is trying to sum a non-numeric number.  i suggest placing some watches on variables (e.g. the row that's throwing the error, the value that's throwing the error, etc) and start debugging from there.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=19JTjCtFPeI will teach you how to use the watch window if not sure

Comment: @jellz77, I appreciate you trying to help. I think I figured out my issue. I have an if statement producing the values, and if they didn't meet the criteria I had them equal to "". So instead of being blank it is trying to add "". Any idea how to make them blank?

Comment: @jellz77 If you add the `DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` to your code I will mark it as the answer. That was more of what I was looking for. The array formula helper column slowed the sheet down significantly more than was acceptable.

Comment: @jellz77 Everything is working now, thanks! I had forgotten to add Scott's `DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` comment. That was just giving me a problem for the lower Half. Just so you know, I am adding some array formulas at the top to return the values at an "easier to see" position. Some of the data I am working with is over 4,000 rows, so the sums were in random positions. This returns the value of the first value `=INDEX(I:I,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(I:I),0))` and this the 2nd `=LOOKUP(2,1/(I:I<>""),I:I)` just to make it easier to see. . Thanks again!

Comment: my pleasure!  just don't forget to mark your question as solved

Answer (score 2):

Using a helper column you will want this array formula to make that helper column.  **This requires that the criteria range values are in all lower case**:

```
=IF(AND(SUM(LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(B2),Criteria,"")))>0,ROW()<MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("capital gain",$B$1:INDEX(B:B,MATCH("ZZZ",B:B)))),0)),1,IF(AND(SUM(LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(B2),Criteria,"")))>0,ROW() > MATCH(2,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("capital gain",$B$1:INDEX(B:B,MATCH("ZZZ",B:B)))),1))),2,0))
```

This will put a 1 for those numbers before and a 2 for those numbers after.

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly the Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Then it is a matter of a quick SUMIF() (I put my formula in Column J)

```
=SUMIF(J:J,1,F:F)
```

and

```
=SUMIF(J:J,2,F:F)
```

[image: ![![![enter image description here]

Comment: I am getting "#N/A" because the cells in column B are not only "Capital Gain", but contain it. For instance, it could say "Box 2a: Total Capital Gain Dist" or "2A. Long Term Capital Gains", etc. The only constant is the "Capital Gain", which is why I was trying to use a search feature, but of course that does not work in a range (at least to my knowledge). It is the same for the other data as well. The cells do not match the criteria cells, but simply contain them.

Comment: My formula is as follows for my helper column: "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Capital Gain",B3555)),"CG",IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH("cg",$I$1:I3554,0)),"1","0"))" but that gives me 1's also in-between the CG's, as well as after. Could this be somehow combined with your array to make the after 2, and in-between 0 as you have them?

Comment: @JRivs just edited it again, it should now find any that have "capital gain" ignoring case.

Comment: @JRivs also make sure you are entering it as an array, with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: @JRivs also make sure the B2s are reference the same row on which the formula resides.  So if you are starting at row 1000 change it to B1000 then copy down.

Comment: Scott, I am getting 0's all the way across the board. I started in B2 as well. Well, I removed the top cell and it is now recalculating (very slow but surely). I will let you know if that fixed my dilemma.

Comment: So the values in B are not exact matches to the values in criteria?

Comment: Scott, that would be correct. I apologize for not clarifying. They are similar to the capital gain issue. Also, I should mention I will eventually need a macro code to apply this formula. Which, I know how to do typically, but are array formulas different?

Comment: @JRivs see edit.  This method requires that the values in `Criteria` be in lower case.  Since you can control this I figured it would be something you can make happen.

Comment: Scott, I will try that on Monday. I will be out for the day, but I am sure you have it down. Thank you so much!

Comment: Scott, sorry to bring this up again after it has been out of mind for so long. I apologize for not mentioning it earlier. I honestly did not even think to because I never foresaw it being a problem, but I have wildcard characters within my criteria. I wanted to preserve that feature in case the data was not read correctly, or if the spaces were entered as a different type of white space. The data is usually exported from a web-generated PDF, so it usually reads fine. But there have been known mistakes a few times. Nonetheless, that is causing the problem. Can this be accounted for?

Comment: If not, or if you do not feel like messing with this anymore, I understand. Upon removing the wildcards, everything worked perfectly. So it is just whether or not there is a way to allow them to stay and search in the same manner excel normally does. So sorry again, and thank you for everything you have done!